# Get Saturday DateTime 4 weeks forward, and 13 weeks back

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to make a custom collection of **DateTime** objects that represent all Saturdays from the current date time to 4 weeks forward, and 13 weeks back. I am trying to order this collection by that which is most recent in regards to the current datetime at the top of the collection.

TIA!

Comment: So what's your question? Where are you having difficulty? Have you looked at the MSDN documentation for `DateTime` and all the functions and properties there?

Comment: Also, define *most recent* since you are projecting 4 weeks into the future.

Comment: edited in regards to the above

Comment: Yeah, that still isn't clear. If you want them ordered *descending* then you just need to say that. If not, then you are still ambiguous. What is "at the top of the collection" if it's initially unsorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

It iterates through the weeks you need from `-13` to `+4` weeks from the current date and adjusts the specific day to the one you need (in this case `Saturday`)

```
for (int i = -13; i <= 4; i++)
{
    var dateBackWithIWeeks = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i * 7);
    switch (dateBackWithIWeeks.DayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
            dateBackWithIWeeks = dateBackWithIWeeks.AddDays(-1);
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Monday:
            dateBackWithIWeeks = dateBackWithIWeeks.AddDays(5);
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
            dateBackWithIWeeks = dateBackWithIWeeks.AddDays(4);
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
            dateBackWithIWeeks = dateBackWithIWeeks.AddDays(3);
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
            dateBackWithIWeeks = dateBackWithIWeeks.AddDays(2);
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Friday:
            dateBackWithIWeeks = dateBackWithIWeeks.AddDays(1);
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
            break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(dateBackWithIWeeks.Date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED BASED ON COMMENTS**

Note: Code may need to be adjusted depending on how you define '13 weeks ago' (and '4 weeks from now') - are you considering calendar weeks, or literally 13 * 7 days? The code below looks back 13 * 7 days.

Here's one way to do it:

1. Create a start date of today minus 13 weeks
2. Adjust the start date to the next Saturday (if it isn't a Saturday)
3. Create an end date of today plus 4 weeks
4. For every 7 days from start to end, add the day to a list
5. Order the list by date, descending

Here's a sample implementation:

```
var saturdays = new List<DateTime>();
var daysInWeek = 7;

var startDate = DateTime.Today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(13 * daysInWeek));

// Adjust start date so it is the first Saturday after 13 weeks before today
startDate = startDate.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Saturday - startDate.DayOfWeek);

var endDate = DateTime.Today.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(4 * daysInWeek));

for (var curDate = startDate; curDate <= endDate; curDate = curDate.AddDays(daysInWeek))
{
    saturdays.Add(curDate);
}

// Order by date, descending
saturdays = saturdays.OrderByDescending(d => d).ToList();

// Output list of Saturdays to console for verification
saturdays.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s.ToShortDateString()));
```

Comment: Surely once you've found a Saturday you should at least start skipping by 7 days instead of 1?

Comment: @MattBurland Updated code so that start date is a Saturday, and then loops every 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var start = DateTime.Now;
    var saturdays = GetSaturdays(start, 13, 4).OrderBy(d => Math.Abs((start - d).Days));
    foreach (var s in saturdays) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.ToLongDateString());
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetSaturdays(DateTime start, int weeksBack, int weeksForward)
{
    var startingSat = start.AddDays(6 - (int)start.DayOfWeek);
    for (int i = -weeksBack; i < weeksForward; i++)
    {
        yield return startingSat.AddDays(i * 7);
    }
}
```

Your question is still a little unclear on how you want these ordered, but you can change the ordering to reflect whatever it is you want. It sounds like you want them ordered by how close they are to the start date which almost certainly doesn't make sense. If you just want them ordered by date descending (which is what you should have said if that's what you *actually* want) Then just replace the `OrderBy` with:

```
.OrderByDescending(d => d);
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vVArbq)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<DateTime> saturdays = new List<DateTime>();
for (int i = -13; i < 4; i++)
    saturdays.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i * 7 - (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Saturday)));
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
var more_recent = saturdays.OrderBy(day => Math.Abs(today.Subtract(day).Days)).ToList();
```